# Use RBD in kubernetes error

Tags: kubernetes, ceph

I follow the [example](http://kubernetes.io/v1.0/examples/rbd/) to use rbd in kubernetes, but can not success. who can help me!! the error :

```
Nov 09 17:58:03 core-1-97 kubelet[1254]: E1109 17:58:03.289702    1254 volumes.go:114] Could not create volume builder for pod 5df3610e-86c8-11e5-bc34-002590fdf95c: can't use volume plugins for (volume.Spec){Name:(string)rbdpd VolumeSource:(api.VolumeSource){HostPath:(*api.HostPathVolumeSource)<nil> EmptyDir:(*api.EmptyDirVolumeSource)<nil> GCEPersistentDisk:(*api.GCEPersistentDiskVolumeSource)<nil> AWSElasticBlockStore:(*api.AWSElasticBlockStoreVolumeSource)<nil> GitRepo:(*api.GitRepoVolumeSource)<nil> Secret:(*api.SecretVolumeSource)<nil> NFS:(*api.NFSVolumeSource)<nil> ISCSI:(*api.ISCSIVolumeSource)<nil> Glusterfs:(*api.GlusterfsVolumeSource)<nil> PersistentVolumeClaim:(*api.PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource)<nil> RBD:(*api.RBDVolumeSource){CephMonitors:([]string)[10.14.1.33:6789 10.14.1.35:6789 10.14.1.36:6789] RBDImage:(string)foo FSType:(string)ext4 RBDPool:(string)rbd RadosUser:(string)admin Keyring:(string) SecretRef:(*api.LocalObjectReference){Name:(string)ceph-secret} ReadOnly:(bool)true}} PersistentVolumeSource:(api.PersistentVolumeSource){GCEPersistentDisk:(*api.GCEPersistentDiskVolumeSource)<nil> AWSElasticBlockStore:(*api.AWSElasticBlockStoreVolumeSource)<nil> HostPath:(*api.HostPathVolumeSource)<nil> Glusterfs:(*api.GlusterfsVolumeSource)<nil> NFS:(*api.NFSVolumeSource)<nil> RBD:(*api.RBDVolumeSource)<nil> ISCSI:(*api.ISCSIVolumeSource)<nil>}}: no volume plugin matched
Nov 09 17:58:03 core-1-97 kubelet[1254]: E1109 17:58:03.289770    1254 kubelet.go:1210] Unable to mount volumes for pod "rbd2_default": can't use volume plugins for (volume.Spec){Name:(string)rbdpd VolumeSource:(api.VolumeSource){HostPath:(*api.HostPathVolumeSource)<nil> EmptyDir:(*api.EmptyDirVolumeSource)<nil> GCEPersistentDisk:(*api.GCEPersistentDiskVolumeSource)<nil> AWSElasticBlockStore:(*api.AWSElasticBlockStoreVolumeSource)<nil> GitRepo:(*api.GitRepoVolumeSource)<nil> Secret:(*api.SecretVolumeSource)<nil> NFS:(*api.NFSVolumeSource)<nil> ISCSI:(*api.ISCSIVolumeSource)<nil> Glusterfs:(*api.GlusterfsVolumeSource)<nil> PersistentVolumeClaim:(*api.PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource)<nil> RBD:(*api.RBDVolumeSource){CephMonitors:([]string)[10.14.1.33:6789 10.14.1.35:6789 10.14.1.36:6789] RBDImage:(string)foo FSType:(string)ext4 RBDPool:(string)rbd RadosUser:(string)admin Keyring:(string) SecretRef:(*api.LocalObjectReference){Name:(string)ceph-secret} ReadOnly:(bool)true}} PersistentVolumeSource:(api.PersistentVolumeSource){GCEPersistentDisk:(*api.GCEPersistentDiskVolumeSource)<nil> AWSElasticBlockStore:(*api.AWSElasticBlockStoreVolumeSource)<nil> HostPath:(*api.HostPathVolumeSource)<nil> Glusterfs:(*api.GlusterfsVolumeSource)<nil> NFS:(*api.NFSVolumeSource)<nil> RBD:(*api.RBDVolumeSource)<nil> ISCSI:(*api.ISCSIVolumeSource)<nil>}}: no volume plugin matched; skipping pod
Nov 09 17:58:03 core-1-97 kubelet[1254]: E1109 17:58:03.299458    1254 pod_workers.go:111] Error syncing pod 5df3610e-86c8-11e5-bc34-002590fdf95c, skipping: can't use volume plugins for (volume.Spec){Name:(string)rbdpd VolumeSource:(api.VolumeSource){HostPath:(*api.HostPathVolumeSource)<nil> EmptyDir:(*api.EmptyDirVolumeSource)<nil> GCEPersistentDisk:(*api.GCEPersistentDiskVolumeSource)<nil> AWSElasticBlockStore:(*api.AWSElasticBlockStoreVolumeSource)<nil> GitRepo:(*api.GitRepoVolumeSource)<nil> Secret:(*api.SecretVolumeSource)<nil> NFS:(*api.NFSVolumeSource)<nil> ISCSI:(*api.ISCSIVolumeSource)<nil> Glusterfs:(*api.GlusterfsVolumeSource)<nil> PersistentVolumeClaim:(*api.PersistentVolumeClaimVolumeSource)<nil> RBD:(*api.RBDVolumeSource){CephMonitors:([]string)[10.14.1.33:6789 10.14.1.35:6789 10.14.1.36:6789] RBDImage:(string)foo FSType:(string)ext4 RBDPool:(string)rbd RadosUser:(string)admin Keyring:(string) SecretRef:(*api.LocalObjectReference){Name:(string)ceph-secret} ReadOnly:(bool)true}} PersistentVolumeSource:(api.PersistentVolumeSource){GCEPersistentDisk:(*api.GCEPersistentDiskVolumeSource)<nil> AWSElasticBlockStore:(*api.AWSElasticBlockStoreVolumeSource)<nil> HostPath:(*api.HostPathVolumeSource)<nil> Glusterfs:(*api.GlusterfsVolumeSource)<nil> NFS:(*api.NFSVolumeSource)<nil> RBD:(*api.RBDVolumeSource)<nil> ISCSI:(*api.ISCSIVolumeSource)<nil>}}: no volume plugin matched
```

And The template file I used rbd-with-secret.json:

```
core@core-1-94 ~/kubernetes/examples/rbd $ cat rbd-with-secret.json
{
"apiVersion": "v1",
"id": "rbdpd2",
"kind": "Pod",
"metadata": {
    "name": "rbd2"
},
"spec": {
    "nodeSelector": {"kubernetes.io/hostname" :"10.12.1.97"},
    "containers": [
        {
            "name": "rbd-rw",
            "image": "kubernetes/pause",
            "volumeMounts": [
                {
                    "mountPath": "/mnt/rbd",
                    "name": "rbdpd"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "volumes": [
        {
            "name": "rbdpd",
            "rbd": {
                "monitors": [
            "10.14.1.33:6789",
        "10.14.1.35:6789",
            "10.14.1.36:6789"
            ],
                "pool": "rbd",
                "image": "foo",
                "user": "admin",
                "secretRef": {"name": "ceph-secret"},
                "fsType": "ext4",
                "readOnly": true
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

The secret:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: ceph-secret
data:
  key: QVFBemV6bFdZTXdXQWhBQThxeG1IT2NKa0QrYnE0K3RZUmtsVncK
```

the ceph config is in /etc/ceph/

```
core@core-1-94 ~/kubernetes/examples/rbd $ ls -alh /etc/ceph
total 20K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Nov  6 18:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 26 root root 4.0K Nov  9 17:07 ..
-rw-------  1 root root   63 Nov  4 11:27 ceph.client.admin.keyring
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  264 Nov  6 18:38 ceph.conf
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  384 Nov  6 14:35 ceph.conf.orig
-rw-------  1 root root    0 Nov  4 11:27 tmpkqDKwf
```

and the key as :

```
    core@core-1-94 ~/kubernetes/examples/rbd $ sudo cat              
    /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring
    [client.admin]
          key = AQAzezlWYMwWAhAA8qxmHOcJkD+bq4+tYRklVw==
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll get "no volume plugins matched" if the rbd command isn't installed and in the path.

As the example specifies, you need to ensure that ceph is installed on your Kubernetes nodes. For instance, in Fedora:
$ sudo yum -y install ceph-common

I'll file an issue to clarify the error messages.

Comment: Thank you for answered. But The kubernetes cluster base on coreos. Is there any way to do this?